# Multi-Threaded notify-wait issue java Intelij

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing a project in Intelij java, and I have a weird problem.
While I'm debugging, the notify-wait mechanism is working well,
In the other hand when I'm clicking "F9" to skip all breaking points the apllication freezes, for my opinion all my threads are in "wait" mode.
This is the manager that alerts the threads that their name is Agents:

```
synchronized (freeAgentDequeueLock) {
        while (currentMissionToDo != null) {
            updateFreeAgents();
            while (freeAgents.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    freeAgentDequeueLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                updateFreeAgents();
            }


            freeAgent = freeAgents.poll();

            synchronized (freeAgent.getLock()) {
                freeAgent.setCurrentMissionToDo(currentMissionToDo);
                freeAgent.setSecret(secret);
                freeAgent.setAgentToReadyToStartProcess();
                freeAgent.getLock().notify();
            }

            currentMissionToDo = missionsToDo.poll();
        }
    }
```

This is the agent awaking:

```
synchronized (lock) {
        while (!isKilled) {
            while (!readyToStart) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
            counterAwaking++;
            System.out.println("agent.Agent id: "+ id + " awakened " + counterAwaking + " times");
            startDecryptionProcess();
            System.out.println("agent.Agent id: "+ id + " finished the " + counterAwaking + " time, going to wait");
            readyToStart = false;
        }
    }
```

And this is the function that notify the manager:

```
 public void startDecryptionProcess() {
    some code....

    synchronized (freeAgentDequeueLock) {
        freeAgentDequeueLock.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`. Does it make a difference?

Comment: I don't have time to study this code and understand what it is supposed to do, but are you aware that `o.notify()` does not do anything at all if there is no other thread already waiting in an `o.wait()` call?  It's up to you to insure that thread A will not `wait()` for an event for which thread B has _already_ given the notification.

Comment: Who modifies freeAgents?

Comment: 1.Notify all does the same behavior, 2.I'm aware of that because of that I did the syncronzied block. 3. FreeAgent is a list of one agent, in debug he always busy and than alert the manager, if I'm doing F9 it just freezes

Comment: A list of one is a waste. You need to post an [MCVE]

Comment: there is nothing weird. Debugging can't be used to find multi-threading problems. You can try logging.